FlinkSQL Convert TIMESTAMP(3) Column without timezone to BIGINT
I have to convert timestamp column to bigint to map the target column in flinksql and don't want to write custom UDF for it.
Any suggestion??
Column is defined as
max_updated as TIMESTAMP(3) -- no LTZ

and the value appears as
"max_updated": {
    "long": "2024-11-04T22:04:17.793"
}


This question is similar to: Flink SQL timestamp to milliseconds. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Finally UNIX_TIMESTAMP worked and my column of type timestamp(3) can be cast to string
select myts_col,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(myts_col AS STRING)), CAST(myts_col AS STRING),DATE_FORMAT(myts_col,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') from mytable

mycol_ts    conv_col
2024-11-06 06:34:53.316 1730874893

